# Legder Nano S - invalid sender

Tags: node.js, electron, ethereum, hardware-wallet, ledger-nano-s

I'm trying to sign ethereum transaction with Ledger Nano S from NodeJS. It generates hexed transaction, but when I try to send it to the testnet Rinkeby, it returns error 'invalid sender'. I'm building an app with elecrtonJS.

I tried to send this way MEW-generated and the same Ledger-sined hex and it worked. So, I think that signature is incorrect. But why?

When I execute this code, Ledger receives request, shows details of a transaction (amount in eth and address to send) after pressing Ledger's confirm button in a js-console appears an error: 'Error: Returned error: invalid sender' without any details.

Here's code which I use. ([full code](https://gist.github.com/SergeSysoev/dada68d318427f1cdf750bb00e31b980))

```js
ledger.comm_node.create_async().then(function(comm) {
  let eth1 = new ledger.eth(comm);
  let hdk;
  let pathBase;
  let offset = 0;

  eth1.getAddress_async('m/44\'/1\'/0\'/0', false, true)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.publicKey && res.chainCode) {
        hdk = new HDKey();
        hdk.publicKey = new Buffer(res.publicKey, 'hex');
        hdk.chainCode = new Buffer(res.chainCode, 'hex');
        pathBase = 'm';
      } else {
        return;
      }
      let wallets = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const index = i + offset;
        const dkey = hdk.derive(`${pathBase}/${index}`);
        const address = publicToAddress(dkey.publicKey, true).toString('hex');
        wallets.push({
          index,
          address: toChecksumAddress(address),
          tokenValues: {}
        });
      }
      web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallets[0]['address']).then(nonce => {
        let rawTx = {
          nonce: web3.utils.numberToHex(nonce),
          gasPrice: web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
          gasLimit: web3.utils.numberToHex(config.gasLimitFor['eth']),
          to: '0x973F795C5aaaf07f8c8d92d57e945f0239DEDF67',
          value: web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether'))
        };

        let t = new EthTx(rawTx);

        t.v = Buffer.from([t._chainId]);
        t.r = toBuffer(0);
        t.s = toBuffer(0);

        eth1.signTransaction_async('m/44\'/1\'/0\'/0/0', t.serialize().toString('hex')).then(result => {
          const strTx = getTransactionFields(t);

          const txToSerialize = Object.assign(strTx, {
            v: addHexPrefix(result.v),
            r: addHexPrefix(result.r),
            s: addHexPrefix(result.s)
          });

          console.log(txToSerialize);

          const serializedTx = new EthTx(txToSerialize).serialize();

          console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(addHexPrefix(serializedTx.toString('hex')))
            .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log('sendSignedTransaction');
            console.log(err);
          });
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('signTransaction_async');
          console.log(err);
        });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('getTransactionCount');
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err && err.metaData && err.metaData.code === 5) {
      }
    });
  console.log(comm);
});
```

Comment: Solved by setting correct chainId before signTransaction_async. And removing t.r = toBuffer(0);t.s = toBuffer(0);